# Can you display health values for monsters?

Tags: diablo-iii

Is it possible to display actual numerical values of the health of a mob in Diablo 3? I know I can turn on the bars and I found that I can turn on numbers for Players, but not for the mobs (mobiles, monsters, whatever).

I would swear I had this turned on in the open beta as I recall wondering how I could do 8 damage to something with 8 health and not kill it. It would leave it with a little bar.

Anywho, I am interested in this display as it just helps me compare the numbers and such better as I look to build an effective DPS character. Helps with estimating time/attacks till death of targets and the like.

(If this is just a check box I can not find I am going to be fairly annoyed)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Sure you can.**

[image]

The problem is, it doesn't show the numbers if the enemy is at full health.

To enable this:[image]

**You can also press** <kbd>V</kbd> **to enable/disable this at any time.**