# How much health does my Mystic Ally have?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

I cannot see the exact amount of heath my Mystic Ally has.  I tried having it take damage to see if it would show a health bar [(similar to monster's health)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/66661/9983), but this did nothing.  How do I know how much health he has?  Does it ever increase?

[image]

Comment: Does it not show up in the top-left corner like the Witchdoctor's dogs?

Comment: @RavenDreamer - It does not show an amount.  Just a bar.

Comment: That's as good as you're going to get.

Comment: She has one health, very fragile.

Comment: Much more than one health xD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Mystic Ally most likely has the exact same hitpoints and armor as you have.

I tested this by getting out of my armor and having a single enemy attack me, I was a sliver of health from death after 8 hits. I then cast the Mystic ally and it was nearly dead after 8 hits.

I'm not counting in the hits I dodged, and in my test the Ally did not dodge a single hit.