# Monk mystic ally attack speed

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

How quickly does my mystic ally attack? I know it has 40% weapon damage, but without the speed that says almost nothing

Answer (score 1):

I believe your Mystic Ally is an exact copy of yourself, which would include your attack speed

Someone did [a test to verify that the HP is the same](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/67554/8462), so I think it's safe to assume all the other stats are the same as well (except run speed... I'm jealous of her run speed)

Comment: I'm jealous of the fact that mine's made out of _fire_